# Java - Generic function to parse enums from strings

Tags: java, templates, generics, enums

I need to create a generic function that will parse enums from strings, but i'm not sure about the syntax to use.

This doesn't work, but it illustrate what i want to do :

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> getEnum( some params, <E extends Enum<E>> defaultVal )
{
    // Some stuff

    return E.valueOf( enumAsString );
}
```

What is wrong in my syntax please ?
Thank you :)

EDIT : Also how do i use this ? In C++ i would do `SomeEnum e = getEnum<SomeEnum>( ... );`

EDIT :

Let

```
enum EnumA
{
    A_A, A_B, A_C
};

enum EnumB
{
    B_A, B_B, B_C
};
```

I would like to do :

```
String enumAsStr = "A_B";
EnumA ea = getEnum< EnumA >( enumAsStr, "A_A" );

enumAsStr = "B_C";
EnumB eb = getEnum< EnumB >( enumAsStr, "B_A" );
```

Comment: Am I getting this right: You want to find an Enum by one of its elements given as String?

Comment: Yes the enum as it appears in the source code is stored in the given string, and i also pass a default value in case the parsing fails.

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is called "reflection".

Comment: Yes but that's very vague. I know how to get the value of an enum from it's name, i just don't know the Java syntax to use for a function returning a generic type that can only be an enum.

Comment: Ah, ok. I see. So I guess Edwin has your answer.

Comment: Yeah it solves my problem, but i still wonder what would be the syntax if i needed to do it like in my example

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like

```
public <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum( String text, Class<E> klass){
   return Enum.valueOf(klass, text );
}
```

So, for instance if there is an enum Letter

```
public enum Letter { A, B, C}
```

You could use it like this:

```
Letter someLetter = getEnum("A", Letter.class);
System.out.println(someLetter); //A
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That looks to be what i'm looking for, but in my example the last parameter was used for a default enum to return in case the parsing fails.
In my example "E" reprensts my enum type right ? Can't i do `E.valueOf(someString)` ?

Comment: Couldn't i do instead : `public <E extends Enum<E>> E getEnum( String text ) { Class< E > klass; return Enum.valueOf( klass.class, text ); }`

Comment: You can't. Enum.valueOf need a class of some enumerate to do its works. And beside, you don't initialize it, and if you could, you would have problems with type erasure.